# typescript restrict function property object keys with interface properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a typescript interface and I want to restrict the function parameter object to have only properties of the `App` interface as keys I tried using `Record` as well as normal `{}`(object) type but in vain.

```
interface App {
  a:'a',
  b: 2,
  c?:'c'
};
```

This is how my interface looks.

```
function func(filter: Record<keyof App ,unknown>){

};

func({a:'a'});
```

this is how i tried using `Record` but it gives me error:

> Argument of type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"a" | "b" | "c", unknown>'.
> Type '{ a: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<"a" | "b" | "c", unknown>': b, c(2345

```
function func(filter: {[K in keyof App]: unknown}){    
}
    
func({a:'a'});
```

this gives me:

> Argument of type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: unknown; b: unknown; c?: unknown; }'.
> Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type '{ a: unknown; b: unknown; c?: unknown; }'

which is understandable since `in` operator expects all the keys to be passed but how do i create a type where i can restrict the `filter` object keys to be properties of the interface App but not necessary that i need to send all the properties. is it possible to achieve such a thing in typescript if yes how?

Comment: Maybe like this ```Partial<{[K in keyof App]: unknown}>```?

Comment: `Partial<Record<keyof App ,unknown>>` should work

Comment: Alternative approach : {[K in keyof App]?: unknown}
Basically it is the same which @TitianCernicova-Dragomir sugested

Comment: @captain-yossarian I usually find predefined types are easier to read for most people, but yes those two are equivalent